# Sufficient conditions for a $3 \times 3$ matrix to be diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that

- $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=2$ as two of its eigenvalues.
- rank$(A+I)=1$.

I am trying to show that A is diagonalizable.

I know that from the nullity theorem that the  multiplicity of eigenvalue -1 is 2.

And I need 3 linearly independent eigenvectors to prove that A is diagonalizable.

So my questions are:

1. How can I say that 2 independent eigenvectors correspond to the eigenvalue -1? Or can I say something like that?
2. How can I be sure what will correspond to the eigenvalue 2?

I am a bit confused.

Comment: there are only two possible Jordan forms for the $\lambda_1$ block, and you can see only the diagonal one is possible.

Comment: @Ataberk The fact that "the multiplicity of eigenvalue -1 is 2" is equivalent to the statement that you can get 2 linearly independent eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{rank}(A + I) = 1$, we have that $\dim(\operatorname{null}(A + I)) = 2$. In other words, the $0$ eigenvalue of $A + I$ has a geometric multiplicity of $2$.

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two linearly independent vectors spanning $\operatorname{null}(A + I))$ (i.e., the $0$ eigenspace of $A + I$).

The claim is that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = -1$. This is easily checked through:
$$\begin{align}
A v_i &= (A + I - I) v_i\\
&= (A + I)v_i - v_i\\
&= (-1) v_i
\end{align}$$

**Edit**:
Thus, the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1 = -1$ has a geometric dimension of two. For your second question, there exists at least one eigenvector corresponding $\lambda_2 = 2$ (otherwise it wouldn't be an eigenvalue). That is, every eigenspace has a geometric dimension of at least one.